# Java- Set Interface - Parse JSON String in order

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, set

I have Spring MVC application.

I have the following JSON String sent from client

```
{
  "cfgName": "Name",
  "cfgfieldses": [
    {
      "cfgsName": "form.0",
      "cfgValue": "someVal"
    },
    {
      "cfgsName": "form.2",
      "cfgValue": "hello"
    },
    {
      "cfgsName": "form.3",
      "cfgValue": "fname"
    },
    {
      "cfgsName": "form.1",
      "cfgValue": "how?"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have two classes to parse this

**Config.java**

```
public class Config implements Serializable {
    private String cfgName;
    private Set<CfgFields> cfgFieldses = new HashSet<CfgFields>(0);

    //getters and setters
}
```

**CfgFields.java**

```
public class CfgFields implements Serializable {
    private String cfgsName;
    private String cfgValue;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Here is my controller

```
public void saveConfig(@RequestBody Config config) {
    System.out.println(config.getCfgName());
    for (Cfgfields cfgfields: config.getCfgFieldses()) {
        System.out.println(cfgfields.getCfgsName());
    }
}
```

The `cfgfieldses` is not in order I am getting as it is `Set`. This is what I am getting the output.

```
Name
form.1
form.2
form.0
form.3
```

I want to get in ordered way as I send the JSON string from client side. I could try **List** instead of **Set**. But I want to know if there is possibility of using `Set` and getting in ordered way.

My expected output is

```
Name
form.0
form.2
form.3
form.1
```

Comment: LinkedHashSet in stead of hashset? (LinkedHashSet keeps the order of insertion)

Comment: u need to go with list if u want the order sequence .

Comment: @chillworld I tried `LinkedHashSet` already. But it is also not working

Comment: With list you have the same problem(and order)? (then it could be parser of xml)

Comment: I have not tried list. I am trying to use it without List to avoid duplicates.

In other programs I tried LinkedHashSet to convert List to Set and it was working fine for me. But in controller JSON is not setting in order. I don't know why

Comment: If you won't limit yourself to JDK 6 you could use Apache common collections library. Its also sorted in order and you can even add at a specific location ListOrderedSet.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/set/ListOrderedSet.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `HashSet`, use a [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html).

Unlike `HashSet`, which makes no guarantees about the order of its items, a `LinkedHashSet` allows you to iterate its members in the order in which they were inserted.

**EDIT**

If you want to enforce a particular sort order on items in a `Set` (e.g. by the form name), use a `SortedSet`, like `TreeSet`. You will need to provide a custom `Comparator` for your `Cfgfields` class.

Comment: How to create custom comparator based on the order it is coming?

Comment: If you want the items to appear in the order they are read, a `LinkedHashSet` will suffice (This assumes, of course, they are added in the same order they are read)

Comment: But it is not working for for JSON string. Can you read the comment that I have added after question?

Comment: Which JSON parser are you using?

Comment: Can you post the code where you initialize and invoke the parser?

Comment: No code. It's Spring MVC. Do you mean `applicationContext.xml` configuration?

Comment: Hard to tell. Might be a parser bug.